# QGIS Plugin development version compatibility

Tags: qgis, plugins, qt, pyqt

At this time latest QGIS version is 2.4 , QT Version is 5.3.1 and PyQT5.Are these version compatible with each other ?

Once QGIS 2.4 is installed , how does one know which version of QT and PyQT(and Python too..) are required to develop Python,C++ plugins and C++ standalone applications ?

Answer (score 3):

QGIS 2.x uses QT4 and PyQT4. You can check this in the aboutbox.
I don't believe you can use QT5 yet.

Comment: You can build with Qt5 on linux but there isn't packages for that